# Multi attachment email issue

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have a problem with sending mail attachments , when you leave the empty  not including any attachment. Message comes to mail with the extension .asc, it has file size 3 bytes , I would like to stop including this .asc file when attachment was not chosen.

This is the Form code

```
<?php
 /*
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 */
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt","");
    $files = array();
    foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
        $file_name = $file['name']; 
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
            die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
        }
        array_push($files,$file);
    }



    $to = "kontakt@lookslike.pl";
    $from = "www.jakasstrona.eu"; 
    $subject = $_POST['imie']; 
    $message = 'Imię: ' . $_POST['imie'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Nazwisko: ' . $_POST['nazwisko'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'PESEL: ' . $_POST['pesel'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'NIP: ' . $_POST['nip'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data urodzenia: ' . $_POST['data'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data urodzenia: ' . $_POST['data2'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data urodzenia: ' . $_POST['data3'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Obywatelstwo: ' . $_POST['obywatelstwo'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Typ: ' . $_POST['typ'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Numer Dokumentu: ' . $_POST['nr'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data ważności dokumentu: ' . $_POST['datawaz'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Adres, ulica, numer budynku, mieszkania: ' . $_POST['long'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Miejscowosc: ' . $_POST['miejscowosc'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Kod: ' . $_POST['kod'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Poczta: ' . $_POST['poczta'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Województwo: ' . $_POST['woj'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Telefon komórkowy: ' . $_POST['telefonphon'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Telefon stacjonarny: ' . $_POST['telefonstac'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data Wyjazdu: ' . $_POST['datawyj'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data Wyjazdu: ' . $_POST['datawyj2'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Data Wyjazdu: ' . $_POST['datawyj3'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Doświadczenie zawodowe: ' . $_POST['doswiadczenie'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Doświadczenie w pracy zagranicą: ' . $_POST['doswiadczenieza'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Uprawnienia na wózki widłowe: ' . $_POST['uprawnienia'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Język Angielski: ' . $_POST['jezykang'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Język Niemiecki: ' . $_POST['jezyknie'] . "\r\n" .
    $message = 'Uwagi: ' . $_POST['uwagi'] . "\r\n" .
    $headers = "Od: $from";



    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time());  
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; // random


    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multi boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";


    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){

        /*
        if (filesize($files[$x] == 3))
        {
            $y=5;
        }
        */
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $files[$x]['name'];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    }

    // sending

    $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) { 
        echo "<p>Mail został wysłany do $to! </p>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<p>Mail nie został wysłany!</p>"; 
    } 
}   

?>
```

Comment: dont roll your own, use phpmailer or swiftmailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you don't send an attachment, you don't want to add the extra hash. See a simple tutorial here: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

maybe put:

```
if(count($files))
 $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

Though generally, I agree that if you aren't doing this to learn how it is done, use an open source library for this kind of thing as suggested in the comments.